# h264_omx not working with Raspberry Pi on aiortc

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use the [`h264_omx`](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/9f14474c0953b90139c8697a216e4c2cd8ee5504/src/aiortc/codecs/h264.py#L292) encoding on the RPI, but I get this error:

```
[h264_omx @ 0x68500890] libOMX_Core.so not found
[h264_omx @ 0x68500890] libOmxCore.so not found
[libx264 @ 0x68502040] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x68502040] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
```

However:

1. I build ffmpeg from source enabling omx; here are the steps i follow:

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install cmake libomxil-bellagio0 libomxil-bellagio-dev
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland.git
cd userland
./buildme
wget https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-6.0.tar.xz
tar -xf ffmpeg-6.0.tar.xz && cd ffmpeg-6.0
./configure --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi
make && sudo make install
```

2. if i test the `omx` encoder from the terminal, on the same RPI

```
ffmpeg -i giphy.gif -c:v  h264_omx giphy.mp4 -y
```

it works. I get this:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
Input #0, gif, from 'giphy.gif':
  Duration: 00:00:02.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6756 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 800x600, 33.33 fps, 33.33 tbr, 100 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> h264 (h264_omx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_omx @ 0x2012100] Using OMX.broadcom.video_encode
Output #0, mp4, to 'giphy.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 800x600, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 33.33 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 h264_omx
frame=   31 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=      24kB time=00:00:00.90 bitrate= 221.5kbits/s speed=1.05x
```

3. If I look for the missing files (`libOMX_Core.so`  and `libOmxCore.so`), I cannot find them anywhere; however, I don't know if they should be somewhere in the first place or it is aiortc which is looking for the wrong files. Here is what I have:

```
ls /opt/vc/lib/
libbcm_host.so    libbrcmOpenVG.so  libdebug_sym.so        libEGL.so        libGLESv2_static.a  libmmal_components.so  libmmal_util.so       libOpenVG.so     libvcilcs.a  libWFC.so
libbrcmEGL.so     libbrcmWFC.so     libdebug_sym_static.a  libEGL_static.a  libkhrn_client.a    libmmal_core.so        libmmal_vc_client.so  libvchiq_arm.so  libvcos.so   pkgconfig
libbrcmGLESv2.so  libcontainers.so  libdtovl.so            libGLESv2.so     libkhrn_static.a    libmmal.so             libopenmaxil.so       libvchostif.a    libvcsm.so   plugins
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!